# How extends User entity of FOSUserBundle?

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, fosuserbundle

I have my UserBundle who extends the FOSUserBundle and works fine. But now, I want create multiple users entities with différents properties.
But the problem is when I create my user enttity who extends my main User entity like this :

```
class User extends BaseUser
{
    protected $id;
    // The main user class who extends FOSUser entity
}

class UserB extends User
{
    //
}
```

When I do this, I've got an error : `

> Access level to MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\UserB::$id must be protected (as in class MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\User).

And when I create a protected id in my UserB entity I have this:

> PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare MyApp\UserBundle\Entity\UserB::$id.

And to finish, I can't delete the id in my User entity less return a Doctrine error :

> [Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]
>       No identifier/primary key specified for Entity 'MTS\UserBundle\Entity\User'. Every           Entity must have an identifier/primary key.

Someone can help me ?

EDIT : Problem solved. My code :

```
/**
 * MTS\UserBundle\Entity\User
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({"userfb" = "UserFB"})
 */
abstract class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @var integer $id
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string $type
     */
    private $type;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table()
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class UserB extends User
{
    // My variables
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You problem appears to be the lack of annotation.

I was able to replicate your 'Every Entity must have an identifier/primary key' error message by removing this from my working code:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
```

The works for me:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx for your answer. Finaly, my problem due to a bad inheritance.
Look at the edit for my code.